# Disable other inputtext on change of one inputtext

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using JSF2.1 with PrimeFaces 4.0 and surprisingly I'm unable to find a simple solution, how to disable a field if another field is already filled instead. E.g. if I enter a number in the "plus quantity" field and I leave the field by clicking or using tab, the "minus quantity" field should be disabled.

All I found is to do something like this

```
<p:inputText id="minusQty" disabled="#{not empty order.plusQty}"/>
<p:inputText id="plusQty" value="#{order.plusQty}">
      <f:ajax update="minusQty" />
</p:inputText>
```

but I find it a bit heavy to call the server for such a simple task. I also don't want to add custom JS code. I guess there's a built-in way in JSF/PF but I cannot find it...

Comment: If you dont want to call the server (I'd use p:ajax instead and you need the value-attribute too) and dont want custom JS code my bet is you're out of luck

Comment: If these are the only possibilities than it's ok. I just thought that there might be some other ways. Something like a built-in jsf / PF client-side validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *but I find it a bit heavy to call the server for such a simple task*

Measure it instead of making assumptions.

> *I also don't want to add custom JS code*

It boils down to just using the right tool for the job. The code which you've so far looks okay, apart from the `<p:ajax>` and `<f:ajax>` mixup (the `<f:ajax>` doesn't support `update` attribute). I'd only use `<p:ajax partialSubmit="true">` to reduce request payload, especially if this is part of a relatively large form.

Might you eventually go in the JS direction, keep in mind that enabling/disabling a HTML DOM element in client side doesn't enable/disable the JSF component in server side. In other words, when you do so with pure JS, then hackers will still be able to submit the value anyway. Always keep this in mind when considering either client or server side for some tasks.